# Python script to write into DynamoDB table came back as error

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

I created a file name - dynamo d b put. py and paste the script below into the file.

```
import boto3

if__name__ == '__main__':
  dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
  table = dynamodb.Table('users')

  response = table.put_item(
    Item={
       'userid': 123,
       'name': "Praveen Sripati",
       'city': "Hyderabad",
       'country': "India"
    }
)
print("Put movie succeeded:")
```

This script is supposed to write into a dynamoDB table. I executed the script and got the error below -

```
line 1: import: command not found
line 3: if__name__: command not found
line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
line 4: `  dynamodb = boto3.resource(' dynamo d b ')'
```

What is the error in this script, please?

Comment: You're missing a space between `if` and `__name__`.

Comment: I got the same error after changing and executing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be a simple syntax error in the definition of your main method, try this:

```
import boto3

if __name__ == '__main__':
  dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
  table = dynamodb.Table('users')

  response = table.put_item(
    Item={
       'userid': 123,
       'name': "Praveen Sripati",
       'city': "Hyderabad",
       'country': "India"
    }
)
print("Put movie succeeded:")
```

Comment: I still got the same error.

Comment: Can you share your entire code and from here are you running it?